# No output on bash program

Tags: bash

Currently working on a bash program to output a string of numbers based off the user input in the arg line command.

When I execute the program I receive the error

```
line 3: [: missing `]'
```

Looking on line led me to believe the error was caused by incorrect syntax but I don't seem to see what that incorrect syntax is. Removing `&&$var < 50` fixes the error but then the program proceeds to output nothing.

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$1
if [ $var > 1&&$var < 50 ]; then
    if [ $var%2 ==  0 ]; then
    $var = $var/2
    echo $var ","
    elif [ $var%2 == 1 ]; then
    $var = 3 * $var + 1;
    echo $var ","
    fi
fi
```

Using shellscript to check the code I have edited it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$1
if [[ $var -gt 1 && $var -lt 50 ]]; then
    if [ "$var%2" ==  0 ]; then
    var=$((var/2))
    echo "$var"
    elif [ "$var%2" == 1 ]; then
    var=$((3*var+1));
    echo "$var"
    fi
fi
```

I no longer receive the original error, however, the code goes through the loop once instead of re-iterating and updating the value of var each time.

Figured out the answer to that last question on my own and the code now compiles and run correctly. Thank you everyone who helped.

Comment: There are quite a few problems with this snippet. Consider running it through [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) to fix the machine detectable issues, then ask humans about the rest.

Comment: Thank you, I have used shellcheck and fixed any errors it found in my code. The code however still outputs nothing.

Answer (score 2):

#### Comparisons

Line 3 is:

```
if [ $var > 1&&$var < 50 ]; then
```

The `&&` operation means that the command is interpreted as if you have:

```
if [ $var > 1
```

followed by `&&` and `$var < 50 ];` — which is not the correct syntax for `test` (aka `[`). When invoked as `[`, the last argument must be `]`; that's why you got the message about "missing `]`".  Also, the relational operators in this context are I/O redirections, not comparators passed to the `[` command.

Spacing matters in shell scripts; don't play cutesy games with spacing and don't take risks.

Use one of:

```
if [ "$var" -gt 1 ] && [ "$var" -lt 50 ]; then
```

or some variant of:

```
if [[ $var > 1 && $var < 50 ]]; then
```

Note that the Bash manual for [`[[`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b) says:

> When used with `[[`, the `<` and `>` operators sort lexicographically using the current locale.

That means they're doing string comparisons, not numeric comparisons.  It also means that when you enter `8`, it doesn't pass the test (`8` compares larger than `50`).  Therefore, you need to use the arithmetic comparators `-gt` and `-lt` even with `[[`:

```
if [[ $var -gt 1 && $var -lt 50 ]]; then
```

#### Arithmetic

Once you've fixed that, you have:

```
if [ "$var%2" ==  0 ]; then
var=$var/2
echo "$var"
elif [ "$var%2" == 1 ]; then
var=(3*$var+1);
echo "$var"
fi
```

Apart from appalling (lack of) indentation, you can be confident that regardless of what you type, `"$var%2"` will never equal 0 because the string contains `%2` at the end.  Similarly with the `elif` condition. You should either just use `else` or include an `else echo "What is $var?"` clause.  If you want to do arithmetic, invoke the arithmetic evaluation:

```
if [ $(( $var % 2 )) ==  0 ]; then
    ((var = $var / 2))
    echo "$var"
else
    ((var = 3 * $var + 1))
    echo "$var"
fi
```

There are numerous alternative ways of writing the arithmetic in Bash.

#### Synthesis

This is code related to the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).  Assembling a complete script gives:

```
#!/bin/bash

var=${1:?}
while [[ $var -gt 1 && $var -lt 50 ]]
do
    if [ $(( $var % 2 )) ==  0 ]; then
        ((var = $var / 2))
        echo "$var"
    else
        ((var = 3 * $var + 1))
        echo "$var"
    fi
done
```

Example output:

```
$ bash xy23.sh 13
40
20
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
$
```

(It was when the run stopped at 8 that I realized the string vs number comparison problem was biting me.)

Comment: `if ((var % 2 == 0))` is even simpler.

Comment: @JohnKugelman `if !(( var % 2 ))`  a bit more, and `if !(( var & 1 ))`  if you care about speed (-:

Comment: True, but readability is more important than character count.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Indeed, using `(( ))` within `[ ]` seems ... perverse somehow. :/

Answer (score 0):

`>` and `<` mean "redirect stdout" and "redirect stdin". Use "-gt" and "-lt" for comparing in test / bash.

There's lots of guides on this out there. [Here's an example.](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)

Answer (score 0):

In [**comparisons**](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)  statements you could use

```
if [[ $var -gt 1 && $var -lt 50 ]]; then
```

Or

```
if [ $var -gt 1 ] && [ $var -lt 50 ]; then
```

Or

```
if [ $var \> 1 ] && [ $var \< 50 ]; then
```

Or

```
if [[ $(( var > 1)) && $(( var < 50 )) ]]; then
```

Or

```
if [ $(( var > 1)) ] && [ $(( var < 50 )) ]; then
```

Or

```
if [[ (( var > 1)) && (( var < 50 )) ]]; then
```

For simple statements, if you wish to use **arithmetic operations** you must follow the [**arithmetic shell expansion**](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) rules

```
var=$(( var/2 ))
```

Or

```
(( var = var/2 ))
```

**Code fixed**:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$1
if [[ $var -gt 1 && $var -lt 50 ]]; then
    if !(( var%2 )); then
        var=$(( var/2 ))
    else
        var=$(( 3 * var + 1 ))
    fi
    echo $var ","
fi
```

Comment: `[ $var \> 1 ]` does lexicographical comparison, not sure if that makes sense.